# Extracting messed up groups or owners inside of Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux

Im trying to write a program that searches through a list of files inside of a directory and will alert me if there is a messed up file.  The messed up files are usually displayed like this `?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? tesfile`

I created a Python program that will search through the different file owners and alert me if it finds one of the files is owned by a user named "?", however the code does not seem to be working properly.

This is the code I originally wrote to try and handle this:

```
input_var=raw_input("Enter path:" )
files=[]
for file in os.listdir(input_var):
        test=getpwuid(stat(file).st_uid).pw_name
        if test=="?":
                print("Critical: "+ file)
```

However oftentimes when I run it on a directory it will throw me an error

```
test=getpwuid(stat(file).st_uid).pw_name OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'auth.log.3.gz'
```

Another example of when I run it on the /home/ directory:

```
File "./PythonTest.py", line 10, in <module>
    test=getpwuid(stat(file).st_uid).pw_name
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ubuntu'
```

Is there a better way to do this, or do you have any better approaches?  I believe the error is caused because it cannot match the ? with any UID, but I am not completely sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the files full path for os.stat.

```
input_var=raw_input("Enter path:" )
files=[]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(input_var):
    for fname in filenames:
        fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
        print(pwd.getpwuid(os.stat(fullname).st_uid).pw_name)
```